# Django- site won't work unless the SECRET_KEY is hardcoded in SETTINGS.PY

Tags: python, django, bash

I changed my django project's settings.py to load the SECRET_KEY as an environment variable:

```
SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
```

Then I stored my variable in **/etc/bash.bashrc**

I set **DEBUG=False**, then restarted gunicorn, restarted nginx and rebooted the server. But my site stopped working (502 Bad Gateway)!

What exactly can be the problem here? I searched but I didn't quite get what might be the issue. The site have been working fine before this change.

---UPDATE---

I stored the variable by opening the .bashrc with nano:

```
sudo nano /etc/bash.bashrc
```

Then added the variable:

```
export SECRET_KEY='***'
```

----UPDATE 2-----

I analyzed the "gunicorn" status using

```
sudo systemctl status gunicorn
```

to see what is stuck and as expected it gave me this:
It is the problem of the secret key !!

```
Mar 06 18:59:33 mymachine gunicorn[15556]:   File "/home/mymachine/mymachine/site/settings.py", line 24, in <module>
**Mar 06 18:59:33 mymachine gunicorn[15556]:     SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
Mar 06 18:59:33 mymachine gunicorn[15556]:   File "/home/atlass/bb_1/bb_0_venv/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
Mar 06 18:59:33 mymachine gunicorn[15556]:     raise KeyError(key) from None**
Mar 06 18:59:33 mymachine gunicorn[15556]: KeyError: 'SECRET_KEY'
Mar 06 18:59:33 mymachine gunicorn[15556]: [2021-03-06 18:59:33 +0000] [15581] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 15581)
Mar 06 18:59:33 mymachine gunicorn[15556]: [2021-03-06 18:59:33 +0000] [15556] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
Mar 06 18:59:33 mymachine gunicorn[15556]: [2021-03-06 18:59:33 +0000] [15556] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
Mar 06 18:59:33 mymachine systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=3/NOTIMPLEMENTED
Mar 06 18:59:33 mymachine systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

---UPDATE 3----

So this is turned into..a plain disgusting and taunting task :/
It turns out the key itself has a problem, I can get it with python and print it, but it won't be imported in django !!!

Any help ??

Comment: Did you do `source /etc/bash.bashrc` after adding the variable to bash.bashrc ?

Comment: @shiva no, but I did now. the error is still there

Comment: How exactly did you store the variable and what does shows us when you run `env` in bash.

Comment: You could try /etc/environment and see if that suits you.

Comment: Your personal environment will be reflected into a systems job. Have a look at https://serverfault.com/questions/413397/how-to-set-environment-variable-in-systemd-service

Comment: @KlausD.I added the key to "gunicorn.service" the way in the answer you gave but the problem is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I managed to get it to work, so here is what I did in "settings.py":

```
from django.utils.encoding import force_bytes, force_str

SECRET_KEY = force_str(os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY'))
```

Notice the force_str() I added to my code; I found about it here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.encoding.force_str

and I added the variable by setting it in my /etc/environment like @JL Peyret suggested.

I should also mention that I uninstalled gunicorn then reinstalled it, but I don't know if that helped in anything.